# How do I get the HTTP URL for an object on Amazon S3 using Botocore?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, botocore

I've always used the Boto library to use Amazon's S3 service, but because of a Python 3.4 project I had to use **Botocore** instead. I've figured out how to do most things, but I can't seem to find how to do one (pretty essential) thing; generating urls.

In Boto I would simply set a `Key` and fire the `generate_url` method. How do I do this in Botocore? I know how to download and save files, but I would much rather just get a link because of server performance and what-not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question because I wanted to use boto with tornado.  There is an asynchronous version of botocore called tornado_botocore, which seems promising.

Taking a look at the S3Connection generate_url method:
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/connection.py

After a quick skim of the code, it looks like the method itself does not require a server request, it simply generates the URL locally.  I was able to verify the lack of a server request by running the following without a network connection:

```
import boto
client = boto.connect_s3()
client.generate_url(60,'GET','test','')
```

This means that this particular boto API is safe to use with tornado. Unfortunately, this doesn't address your Python 3.4 issue.